# How to Correctly typeset two word last name in Bibtex in narrative

Tags: latex, bibtex

This post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204697/how-to-correctly-typeset-an-authors-two-word-last-name-in-bibtex) explains how to use BibTex for an author with multiple parts to a last name.

My question is slightly different. When formatted as below, this gives the correctly formatted reference on my reference page. But, inside the narrative where I use `\cite{doe2024}` it always prints (J.K van der Doe, 2024). what I want instead in the narrative is only (van der Doe, 2024), or just the last name and not the initials.

Of course, using `author={van der Doe}` in the BibTex entry makes this true in the narrative giving what I want there, but then the actual reference on my reference page loses the intial, which I do want there.

```
@article{doe2024,
  title={A title of some kind},
  author={{van der Doe}, Jon K.},
  journal={Journal of Something},
  year={2024},
  volume={1},
  number ={1}}
```

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.